# Alternative to MapPageRoute using the MVC pattern

Tags: asp.net

I want access to some pages of my website with "web.com/software" or "web.com/about", but I'm using the MVC pattern and the MapPageRoute method (inside RouteConfig.cs) only works with pages without controllers.
If Home is my controller and Software the view, I want access with "web.com/software" instead of "web.com/Home/Software".
Is it possible with ASP.NET or I need use rewrites in Web.config (IIS) and .htaccess (Apache)?

```
namespace MyWebsite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("SoftwarePage",
                "software", // web.com/software
                "~/Views/Home/Software");

            //routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use MapPageRoute instead of just MapRoute?

Comment: Either use [MapRoute](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) or [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx).

Comment: Solved. Thanks.
Wiktor: It's the example I've seen, sorry.

Comment: I have reverted your question. You need to post your solution in the dedicated answer box rather than editing it into your question.

Comment: Dedicated answer box? What's this? Where's it?